# MissingKeyMapError, related to domains?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am Using Google Maps API to display google reviews. Works on our development domain but when I update the vhost to a different production domain it fails. I don't get why it would matter if I uses our.dev.com or our.site.com. Has anyone seen this before ? It's not a server issue as I can replicate the problem on the same box.

Browser Console:

```
js?libraries=places:34 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

 _.kb @ js?libraries=places:34
```

EDIT: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION as it does not match the same problem. This DOES work at times depending on the domain opposed to the "duplicate" question that doesn't work at all.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question @geocodezip

Comment: Keys are now required. Domains that work without a key are grandfathered to keyless access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps JavaScript API requires an API key.

You can find description of the error in the documentation:

> **MissingKeyMapError** The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

An API key was announced as mandatory parameter on June 22, 2016:

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Domains that were known before June 22, 2016 were "grandfathered", so they allow keyless access, but new domains created after June 22, 2016 must use API keys.

Comment: I've seen this already, the problem is that it doesn't work when I change to  a different domain, I guess it 's aproblem on my end which I will need to sort out, thanks for responding.